# the $10,000 CAD limit is it by person or by family

Tags: air-travel, canada, money

I know you are allowed to travel with up to $10,000 CAD or equivalent in foreign currency. I will be travelling overseas with my wife soon. Am I allowed $10,000 CAD and my wife is also allowed $10,000? or only $10,000 CAD for the both of us?

Comment: Are you asking about an amount being taken out or brought in?

Comment: As far as Canada is concerned you are allowed to enter or leave with as much cash as you want. The only issue is [whether you have an obligation to report the amount](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/ttd-vdd-eng.html). I've never found an authoritative source describing how the $10,000 threshold is applied to families travelling together (perhaps others have), though many assume it is per-family based on the fact that [Form E311](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/publications/forms-formulaires/e311-eng.html) asks if "we" are carrying that amount. It would be safest to report it.

Comment: The $/€/£ 10000 amount is the **threshold** where you must **declare** the amount you are taking with you. So there is no limit per person as such. Many customs services offer a pdf form that can be filled out beforehand.

Comment: Is there some reason you need to carry such a large amount of cash? For most people it would be unwise whether it's allowed or not.

Comment: @ChrisH Carrying cash maybe risky, but it is also likely to be the cheapest option if you are already physically making the trip, as there are zero fees and taxes that would be imposed by various transfer services.

Comment: Just a quick warning: make sure not to transit in the United States with this much cash. They love ~stealing~ civil forfeiting that. As for reasons, I obviously can't know where OP is from but just as an example, Iran is under sanctions and you can't just wire money there.

Answer (score 5):

The Canadian government websites are not very clear on this point.  For example this national website is written entirely in terms of one traveller and makes no mention of a family unit:
https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/ttd-vdd-eng.html

But this one for Ontario (which I would expect follows the same rules as the rest of Canada) says it's $10,000 per family: https://settlement.org/ontario/immigration-citizenship/landing-and-leaving/landing-in-canada/how-do-i-bring-money-into-canada-proof-of-funds/

Probably the best is just to declare if your family is carrying more than $10,000.  You shouldn't get in trouble for declaring when it was not legally required to do so.  And you are allowed to carry more than $10,000 so long as you declare it.